Analogy about enthalpy and internal energy
In my book i saw many reactions with enthalpies of reactions, and tried to use an analogy
[Note that this is for constant pressure conditions, as the reactions in my book are based on that... this is not correct for variable pressure conditions]

Wrong Analogy:

say i earn 10(the internal energy change) the expense 2(PV=work to make space) now, enthalpy change is (10+2), but this dosen't seem to make sense to me, why add expense, enthalpy change is the actual energy we got from the bonds, i shoud deduct my expense not add it, and i remained confused
i came up with another better analogy to exlpain this

Correct Analogy

internal energy change has a work term in it (deltaU = q+w), the q term in internal energy change this is the actual income (10), the work done term is the expense(PV=2), so its (internal energy change) like the person giving us the salary is paying for our expenses from our paycheck, so our salary is not the ACTUAL money we earned, we need to add the expense, the amount that was taken form the total salary to find the actual amount we earned ! so i earned 10 (q), but get 8(after removing expenses) to find what i actually earned i add 8+2 = 10
[I think that energy released in a reaction is purely heat(mostly) and this is represented by enthalpy(constant pressure) now it does work to occupy space, stuff and looses some energy, internal energy change accounts for this resultant(remaining) energy]
this seems to make sense, i need to know if this is how it works, i am correct ?

wait... so heat term q is the actual energy obtained from all reactions !? we lose a part of this through work done as these are the primary ways for enegy transfer to occur

if we a re talking about enthalpy then by default isn't it iso-baric ? (well, that's what i considered). Anyways for a 12th grader most questions involving enthalpy come in iso-baric conditions, i am aware that it is not the case in non-isobaric conditions, for an isobaric process this analogy could be considered ?

constant pressure conditions would be the correct term instead of what i said, am i right ?, so constant pressure condition is the most common one where reactions occur, that's why we defined enthalpy right ?

More exactly, the requirement is the initial and the final pressure must be the same, it can change during the process. The enthalpy change would be the same. (but W and Q may differ, being path dependent).

Enthalpy is defined for states, not processes, as states do not involve the notion of variability of parameters.
But, differences of enthalpy between endpoint states is usually considered for isobaric processes, when enthalpy usage brings significant advantage. The term $p \Delta V$ from $\Delta(pV)$ cancels the volume work term of internal energy $-p \Delta V$ and the term $V \Delta p = 0$:
$$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta(pV) = Q + W + p\Delta V + V \Delta p + \Delta p \Delta V = \\ = Q - p \Delta V  + p\Delta V + V \Delta p + \Delta p \Delta V =  Q $$
More exactly, for the isobaric process and enthalpy, the requirement is the initial and the final pressure must be the same, but the value of the pressure along the path does not matter. The enthalpy change would be still the same. But the path, i.e. the pressure profile along it, does matter for W and Q. Their values may differ, being path dependent. So better to keep the pressure constant.

Enthalpy change at isobaric conditions can be formally considered as if a system stored energy not only as its internal energy, but also as its "external energy" via the volume work against the constant pressure of the surrounding.
Expanding is like storing this "external energy" in the environment.
Contracting is like releasing this stored "external energy" from the environment.
For that reasons, molar heat capacities of ideal gases differ:
$$C_\text{p} = C_\text{V} + R$$
where the R term can be formally viewed as "heat capacity of the environment".

I found this confusing: "More exactly, for the isobaric process and enthalpy, the requirement is the initial and the final pressure must be the same, pressure can change during the process." Is there a typo at the end (pressure cannot change...) ?

Interesting, never thought of R as the heat capacity of the surroundings.

@BuckThorn No, it is not a typo.  Clarification: For Delta H_p, the important is only p_init=p_final, as it does not depend on the path. But W and Q are path functions so if p is not constant, then generally  \Delta H <> Q. the left is always the same, the right one is not.   // R as surr capacity -Formally, as a mental helper. Part of Q externally stored in surrounding via W_volume. And only for ideal gases, as only for them C_p - C_V = R.

Ok, I'm not sure I follow the first bit (I understand the bit about R). In any case, this inequality is not generally true: $\Delta(pV) = p\Delta V + V \Delta p + \Delta p \Delta V$. Rather $\Delta(pV) = \int pdV + \int Vdp $.

@BuckThorn pV is a state variable by itself and its difference cannot be path dependent, so there is no need for integration along  path(p,V). Mathematically, Delta (pV) = p2.V2 - p1.V1 = (p1+ delta p)(V1 + delta V) - p1.V1 = p1.delta V + V1.delta p + delta p . delta V =(if p constant) p1 . delta V .

Yes, you are right about this being general. I'll have to crack open my thermo book for a refresher. //However I can't help but still see a non-sequitur in  "More exactly, for the isobaric process and enthalpy, the requirement is the initial and the final pressure must be the same, pressure can change during the process". Evidently you mean that the pressure along the path doesn't matter, but the wording is confusing.

@BuckThorn You may be right about my wording, I am famous, not limited to SE, that my formulation may seem uneasy to get sometimes. It happened few times that even I did not understand what I have meant by that. :-) I have modified the wording.
